# Analog Peak Filter

Tags: analog, frequency, sound

[image]

I'm currently working on a project building headphone and to had to build filters to cancel certain unwanted frequency. While researching and working on it, i came across a reference design which requires Peak filters. Unfortunately, there were very few sources out there on Peak filter and they dont really talk much about it or how the calculation is done. It will be really helpful if someone out there is able to explain to me more about analog peak filters.

Thanking in advance.

Comment: So, where's the reference design you talk about. Last time I checked nobody here is a mind reader.

Comment: @Andyaka  Sorry about that, it was a reference design from a audio company and uploading a pic of the circuit here might get me into trouble. But i could describe it. its almost similar to notch filter, but with an additional resistor at the input and a capacitor on the output. hope that helps :)

Comment: No that doesn't help at all. There are dozens of ways of designing a notch filter so adding a resistor to one part and a capacitor to another is meaningless.

Comment: @Andyaka  I'll try to just crop the peak filter part and post the pic here. :)

Comment: Is C49 fed by the output of an op-amp and does R46 return to that same op-amp's inverting input?

Comment: @Andyaka  Yes it is. the C49 is fed by the output of an op-amp and the R46 returns to the same op-amp's inverting input.

Answer (score 1):

The full circuit comprises an op-amp with a twin "T" notch filter in the feedback of the op-amp. This turns a notch filter into a peaking band-pass filter because, at the "notch" frequency, there is little feedback and the gain becomes quite high. This sort of circuit is usually "restrained" by a normal feedback resistor in parallel with the notch filter but sometimes it isn't used if the basic notch filter hasn't got high selectivity.

Twin T notch filter: -

[image]

The cut-off frequency is defined as fc = \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi RC}\$

Answer (score 0):

It's a while since I've done any filter design, but I'd first start with modelling the circuit. Set up all the equations, and do some calculations on the various frequencies. What bandwidth are you operating in? For headphones and Audio in general, I'd want a very flat response. Having a too strong peak will cause certain frequencies being too prominent (you basically end up with a hard-wired EQ section)

The above part is very straight forward, but it would really help if you could at least post a picture of the circuit. Most basic filter designs are not proprietary. Is it passive? active?

Here's the wikipedia article on Electronic filters, which should explain most things fairly well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_filter

Comment: This isn't really an answer - it's a few generalities about filter design. I'm aware you can't post comments because you haven't enough reputation and, ironically your rep will drop for forcing a poor answer -1.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have done some reading but im unable to find any reference on peak filter. Im not sure if its a type of a filter or just a name used by the company who created the reference design.